# Search questions by last active date

Tags: discussion, badges, search

For the two badges [Excavator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator) and [Archaeologist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist), you need to edit posts that are 6 months old (1 and 100), respectively. Of course, finding a random post that happens to be 6 months old is very difficult, so is there any way that you can search for a post that is a certain age?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching (Advanced Search options include date logic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the site search to find questions that were last active 6 months ago:

> [`is:q lastactive:6m`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20lastactive%3a6m&mixed=0)

and you can amend that with your favorite tag or other aspects.

Look at the [Searching help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for more options you can use to filter your resultset.

If you want to have even more control, consider [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) or try one of the already existing queries found on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244876/158100)